# Scaling x axis and y axis with VegaLite.jl

Tags: julia, vega-lite

I have plotted a scatter plot in `VegaLite.jl`, however, the x-axis and y-axis don't get scaled automatically like other plotting packages (plots, plotly etc.)

For example in the following example, the plot starts x-axis from 0, whereas it would make more sense to start from a value such as 125 since x-values are clustered between 150-200. The same thing applies to the y-axis. This results in a plot that has only utilized the top right section. Any ideas on how to scale the x and y axes?

```
using VegaLite
x = Array{Int64}([150,175,200])
y = Array{Int64}([225,250,275])

@vlplot(
    :point,
    x = x,
    y = y
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `scale` specification, as documented in the [Vega-Lite documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html) or demonstrated *e.g.* [here](https://www.queryverse.org/VegaLite.jl/stable/examples/examples_line_charts/#Connected-Scatterplot-(Lines-with-Custom-Paths)-1) in the `VegaLite.jl` documentation.

For example:

```julia
using VegaLite
using DataFrames

data = DataFrame(x = [150,175,200], y = [225,250,275])

data |> @vlplot(
    :point,
    x = {:x, scale = {zero = false}}, # Auto scale, without enforcing that zero be in the domain
    y = {:y, scale = {domain = (200, 300)}}, # Explicit domain
)
```

[image: Resulting plot]